Mapbox forward api returns incorrect UK postcode suggestions
I am trying to geocode a UK postcode into latitude, longitude values. The autocomplete suggestions returned underneath are not an exact match, even though an exact match exists. I have reproduced this in the v6 playground so as to ensure this is nothing to do with my implementation. See below:

I then delete a character and type it in again and somehow I get the exact match. ie:

(Link to v6 playground with params here)
The only way I can fix this behaviour is to switch off autocomplete for postcodes but that would be a detriment to the user.
What I would like to happen is that the user would get the suggestions up to when there is an exact match - standard behaviour I'd assume.
Is there a way to get around this issue?
